# Apache virtual host into dynamic IP

Tags: apache, configuration, webserver, virtualhost

What I want to achieve is the following:

At any given point in time, if anybody, including me, in the LAN, knows my IP address and in the hosts file he or she has `192.168.1.xxx beta.example.com`, by accessing `beta.example.com` he or she will get beta.example.com served from my apache. This except for me, I can have my own `127.0.0.1 beta.example.com`.

I tried this, which only works locally. For outside connections, it defaults to `DocumentRoot` and the application has trouble getting it's path properly if users attempt to access `http://beta.example.com/example.com/`.

```
    Listen *:80
    ServerName localhost:80
    DocumentRoot "c:/www"

<VirtualHost beta.example.com>
    DocumentRoot "c:\www\example.com"
    ServerName beta.example.com
</VirtualHost>


<Directory "c:\www\example.com">
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

What should I change? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it. Was simple. Replaced `<VirtualHost beta.example.com>` with:

```
   NameVirtualHost *:80
   <VirtualHost *:80>
```